# How to find document with SOLR query and exact string match

Tags: datastax-enterprise

Considering a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  enterprise_id uuid,
  transaction_id text,
  state text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((enterprise_id, transaction_id))
```

and Solr core with default, auto-generated parameters.

How do I construct a Solr query that will find me record(s) in this table that have `state` value exact match to an input, considering the `state` can be arbitrary string?

I tried this with state value of `a+b`. This works fine with `q=state:"a+b"`, but that creates a "phrase query":

```
"rawquerystring": "state:\"a+b\"",
"querystring": "state:\"a+b\"",
"parsedquery": "PhraseQuery(state:\"a b\")",
"parsedquery_toString": "state:\"a b\"",
```

So, the same record is found if I use query like `q=state:"a(b"`, which results into the same phrased query and finds the record with `state` of `a+b`. That is unacceptable to me, because I need an exact match.

I went through https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers, and tried using `q={!term f=state}a+b` or `q={!raw f=state}a+b`, but neither even finds my sample transaction record.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you got `state` generated as a `TextField` where standard tokenization is applied [StandardTokenizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-StandardTokenizer) and then a split is made on `+` and the plus sign itself is discarded. You could use a different tokenizer (whitespace?) or just make state an `StrField` for an exact match.

This works for me with `state` as an `StrField`:

`select * from transactions where solr_query='state:a+b';`

Comment: `StrField` is easier than mucking with a tokenizer, ty :)